# React Hook Form validation with Material UI TextField is not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield, react-hook-form

I'm trying to create form with React Hook Form with Material UI TextField. It seems I configured it properly but the error message doesn't appear and I don't know why. I put just the main parts of the code.

```
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";

type NovoSinistroForm = {
    codigoCobertura: number;
    telefoneResponsavel: string;
    evento: number;
    dataEvento: Date;
    dataEstimadaColheita: Date;
    areaAtingida: number;
    nomeComunicante: string;
    nomeResponsavelVistoria: string;
    relacaoComunicanteResponsavel: string;
    emailComunicante: string;
    telefone1Comunicante: string;
    telefone2Comucante: string;
}

const {
        control,
        formState,
        handleSubmit,
        watch,
} = useForm<NovoSinistroForm>();

<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
   <Controller
    name="nomeResponsavelVistoria"
    control={control}
    rules={{
        required:{
            value: true,
            message: "Campo obrigatório."
        }
    }}
    render={({
        field,
        fieldState: { invalid, isTouched, isDirty, error },
    }) => (
        <TextField
            {...field}
            innerRef={field.ref}
            label="Responsável por vistoria"
            type="text"
            InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
            }}
            error={invalid && isTouched}
            helperText={error?.message}
        />
    )}
/>
</form>
```

OnBlur doesn't seem to be firing
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I finnaly figured it out what the problem was. I had to pass an objet into useForm to configure the validation strategy before user submit the form.

```
const {
        control,
        formState,
        handleSubmit,
        watch,
    } = useForm<NovoSinistroForm>({
        mode: 'onTouched'
    });
```

I hope it can help someone else in future.

Comment: I was facing the same problem, but was able to generate the helper text without doing what you did. But the helper text is not changing for the masked field. Can you [take a look](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-hooks-8zsgbb) since you already solved this problem once?